# How to use a variable defined in code behind file in ASP.NET on inline code for the same page

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, inline-code

I have a page with a `Textbox`, a `Button` and a `Label` control. On Button_Click event, I store the value of Textbox in a `variable` called `S` using code behind.

How do I show the value of `S` in the Label control using `inline` code, but not using the `code behind`?

Answer (score 4):

This is not the ASP.NET approach, but you can add `S` as a member of the code-behind class (at least protected):

```
protected string S { get; private set; }
```

And retrieve it inline in the page markup with

```
<%= S %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about the requirement, but following with some modifications it will work. Embed this block in your aspx page:

If using C#

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       mylabel.Text = s; // Replace with your label control
    }
</script>
```

If using VB.NET:

```
<script runat="server">
    Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)
        mylabel.Text = s
    End Sub
</script>
```